# Reading into ResultSet from SQL Server gives different results in SQL Server 2014 and Sql Server 2016

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have two databases (SQL Server 2014 and Sql Server 2016) which have the same table with the same data. Table has a float field. 
My sql query is as follows 
select Round(val,8) as val from myData;

The original value in the table is 9.83570191 (this value happens to have 8 decimal places, but there are some other values with higher precision which I need to truncate).
When I read it from both Databases with Sql Management Studio, I see both values as 9.83570191 after rounding.

In Java however, I get a strange behaviour. 
I am using JDBC with jtds-1.3.1 to read the data. 
When I read it as Double or String from SQL Server 2014, 
the value I see is 9.835701910000001. 
When I read it from SQL Server 2016, the value is 9.83570191 as expected.

If I remove the Round function from the sql, I get the expected value when reading from both DBs.

Do you think there is a problem with the ROUND function or something funny is going with JTDS?

Please note that this is a simplified example and removed anything that is not appropriate for this question.

Comment: float is tricky, it can't necessarily represent a number such as  9.83570191 exactly - if you want a fixed number of decimal places, use decimal data type - cast it to decimal perhaps?

Comment: If you want an exact representation of a number, you should use the DECIMAL data type, not FLOAT.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My question however is why I get different results when reading from SQL Server 2014 and 2016?

Comment: Maybe one returns float and the other decimal? You might want to check the column type in the result set metadata